# WPF - Listbox - ItemTemplate - Scrolling to top or bottom, resets my default view before selecting anything

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with a Listbox, which i've made my own Datatemplate too.. Actually i've made two.
They contain an image(which looks like a checkbox) and a textblock with some text.

Both of them are made so you can "multiselect". Whenever you click an image in the Listboxitem, it changes to a selected checkbox. (this is done for grahical purpose, instead of regular checkboxes) They are more or less identical, however. One of them has a scrolling issue, When I check some of them,

[My problem] (http://postimg.org/image/h65g38s0x/)!

and scroll all the way down till i reach the bottom of the listbox.

and then go back to the top, just by scrolling, or releasing the mouse at the bottom.

my entire listbox has reset it self, like it was just loaded from the beginning.

Things i've observed:

1) It does not reset the field I have selected (in my example row  4.)
2) This issue occurs also if i hit the top of my scrollbar.
3) Listitems within the view of top and bottom does not reset. (so if im at the bottom, and try to scroll further down, nothing happens to the Listitems that are visible. only those out of sight.

4) If nothing is selected everything resets (adding to observation 1).
5) I've testet ALL events on the listbox, to see if one of them got triggered to reset my listboxes(in hope of a workaround), however no luck.

Things to have in mind.

1) My two listboxes run on two different DataTemplates, however, they are identical, minus the textblock path, images are identical, listboxes are identical, except for their itemtemplates.

2) Each listbox has it's own itemssource bound to a list with objects in it. (List1. string, bool : List2, string, bool, object) List2, is the one failing.

3) The other Listbox works like a charm.

4) I could provide alot of code, but there is a lot to take in, since i don't know where the problem occurs, so i'll provide a snippet.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplateAssignmentTypes">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="StackPanelAssignmentType" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"                 Margin="0 0 0 0" >
                <Form:ImageCheckBox x:Name="ImageCheckBoxState" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Source="/SimaTech.Forms.AssignmentBringBack;component/Images/Checkbox.png" 
                                        Width="24" Height="24" MouseLeftButtonUp="ImageCheckBoxState_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0 0 0">
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockType" Text="{Binding Path=Type}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplateVehicle">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="StackPanelVehicle" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 0 0 0" >
                <Form:ImageCheckBox x:Name="ImageCheckBoxState" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Source="/SimaTech.Forms.AssignmentBringBack;component/Images/Checkbox.png" 
                                        Width="24" Height="24" MouseLeftButtonUp="ImageCheckBoxState_MouseLeftButtonUp"  />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 0 0 0">
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding Path=Vehicle.Name}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


     <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="20 10" Padding="20 0" BorderThickness="2 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource BorderHorizontalSeperator}">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0 5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Gammel dato:" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
                        <DatePicker Name="DatePickerOldDate" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource StyleCalendar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 10 0 0" Width="150" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                        </DatePicker>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Margin="18 5">
                        <TextBlock Text="Ny dato:" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
                        <DatePicker Name="DatePickerNewDate" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource StyleCalendar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 10 0 0" Width="150" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="0 5">
                    <TextBlock Text="Opgave type:" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}" Margin="0 5" />
                    <ListBox Name="ListBoxAssignmentTypes"  Margin="0 0 100 0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplateAssignmentTypes}" >

                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0 0 2 0" Margin="10 10 20 10" Style="{StaticResource BorderHorizontalSeperator}">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Montør/Montørgruppe:" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}" Margin="0 5 0 10" />
                    <ListBox Name="ListBoxVehicles" Margin="0 0 120 0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplateVehicle}" >

                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="StackPanelButtons" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 30 0 0">
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

I have code behind aswell, 
to set and remove my "checkmark" in the image, but this is only triggerede on a mouseupevent, and has nothing to do with scrolling.

It's a strange problem, and I wondered if anyone had an idea, or had experienced it themselves.

EDIT:
Found out that when a listbox has a certain number of listitems, it redraws the listitem back to default. The first list contained only 11 Listitems, the other 25, and the one with 25, failed. I added the same amount to the other listbox, and the same error showed it self.

With the most highest regards 
Max

Comment: *WPF does not support developers with a winforms mentality*. Create a proper ViewModel for these Items and Bind the `CheckBox.IsChecked` to a bool value in the ViewModel and your problem will magically be solved.

Comment: And please, dude, don't use PNGs for everything. WPF is vector-based, not bitmap-based. Your fixed size PNG approach is not going to work well on many different resolutions.

Comment: I have never seen so many `StackPanel`s in my life. If you have display problems and scrolling issues, see if removing them helps. In my experience, `Grid` is king. Oh, and **please provide that code-behind** -- that is probably the source of your problems as well.

Comment: HighCore: Just a minor detail. I havn't really done that much databinding, thats why I was sticking to this solution. About the bitmaps I had no idea, I really only have Photoshop to work with when i'm doing icons and stuff, but I can see why vetor graphics would be more suitable. 

Guttsy: Grid is definately another option i'll consider.

To both of you. I think I know what the error was, and one way of fixing it would be doing it as HighCore would have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left using a Listbox here, since it has some sort of automatic layout refresh/update build in function, which was the cause of my layout reset, and usercontrol presenting an item, which i added to a stackpanel.

This worked for me.